# HttpDelete and parameters

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Created an ASP.NET Core Web API. With the following code, I can execute a Delete just fine from Postman with the Id in body.

```
    [Authorize]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Gigs")]
public class GigsController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

    public GigsController(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }


    //[HttpDelete("{gigId}"]
    [HttpDelete]
    public IActionResult Cancel([FromBody] int gigId)
    {
        var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);

        var gig = _context.Gigs.Single(g => g.Id == gigId && g.ArtistId == userId);
        gig.IsCancelled = true;

        _context.SaveChanges();

        return Ok();

    }

}
```

[image]

However, when I execute it via my webpage using the following JS code, I get a 500 Error. What is the correct way to pass the body text? I have also tried sending it as parameter without the [FromBody] and/or with [HttpDelete ("{gigId}")]

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".js-cancel-gig").click(function(e) {
            var link = $(e.target);
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this gig?")) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/api/gigs/",
                    method: "DELETE",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ "gigId": link.attr("data-gig-id") }),
                    success: function() {
                        link.parents("li").fadeOut(function() {
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert("something failed");
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Postman you're sending a scalar "3" but in JS you're sending an object with a property called `gigId` that has a value of 3.  You probably want `data` to be in form-data format like `gigId=3` instead of using JSON.  Or change your endpoint to accept an object with a property called `gigid`.

Comment: so the code works as is for an HttpPost with just the addition of the FromBody, but the same doesnt work for the HttpDelete? I tried just adding url: "/api/gigs/" + link.attr("data-gig-id"), but that didnt work either

Comment: Figured it out, needed to modify the data annotation to HttpDelete("{gigId}")]